# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when calling X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, mono, rsa

I tried create a X509Certificate2 object with a public rsa key for encryption in Unity with c#. I get the following exception:

```
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative. 
> Parameter name: length 
> System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs:348)
> Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.PEM (System.String type, System.Byte[] data) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs:601)
```

.

```
static loadKey() {
    //get rsa public key
    byte[] data = GetBytes("MIIBIjANBgkqhk......EuH+zIXFzvirHQ2AxE/5wIDAQAB");

    Debug.Log(data.Length);

    X509Certificate2 x509certificate = new X509Certificate2(data);
    //[...]
}
```

This is the GetBytes function

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

For the record: data.Length is 784

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you believe you data represents an X509 certificate?

Comment: I generated and encoded the key in java. It doesn't work with or without the "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" and "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

Comment: That's because it's not an X509 certificate.

Comment: A public key isn't a certificate in the same way that a motor is not an automobile. It's the most important aspect of a certificate (together with the signature), but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. A certificate is defenately not a key so i finally managed to get a working function to encrypt a string with bouncycastle:

```
static string Encrypt2(string publicKeyFileName, string inputMessage)
{  
    try
    {
        // Converting the string message to byte array
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] inputBytes = enc.GetBytes(inputMessage);

        AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter(publicKeyFileName);

        // Creating the RSA algorithm object
        IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher =  new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        // Initializing the RSA object for Encryption with RSA public key. Remember, for encryption, public key is needed
        cipher.Init(true, publicKey);

        //Encrypting the input bytes
        byte[] cipheredBytes = cipher.ProcessBlock(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipheredBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Any errors? Show them
        Debug.Log("Exception encrypting file! More info:");
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
    return "";

}


public static AsymmetricKeyParameter ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter(string pemFilename)
{
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenText(pemFilename);
    var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(fileStream);
    var KeyParameter = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
    return KeyParameter;
}
```